# Sequentially closure on Hilbert separable space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, weak-topology

Let $H$ a Hilbert separable space with a Hilbert basis $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$. Let
$$
 F = \{e_m + m e_n \, : \, n,m \geq 1\}
$$

1. Show that 0 is not in the sequentially weak closure of F.
2. Show that 0 in sequentially weak closure of sequentially weak closure of F

Any hint of suggestion?

I tried by contradiction but I'm stuck

Comment: If $x_k=e_{m_k}+m_ke_{n_k}$  is weakly convergent then $x_k$ is bounded. Therefore $m_k$ is bounded i.e. admits finitely many values. It can be split into finitely many subsequences each convergent weakly to some $e_m,$ i.e. not to $0.$ For every fixed $m$ the sequence $n\to e_m+me_n$ tends weakly to $e_m.$ Hence $e_m$ belongs to the sequential weak closure of $F.$ In turn the sequence $m\to e_m$ tends weakly  to $0.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc: +1, but you should type the answer in the "answer" box :)

Comment: @MartinArgerami Ok. I have put it in the answer box.

Comment: Nice. Upvoted. $ \ $

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume the sequence $x_k=e_{m_k}+m_ke_{n_k}$ is weakly convergent to $x.$ Then $x_k$ is bounded say by $N,$ by the uniform boundedness theorem.  Therefore the sequence  $m_k$ is bounded, because $N\ge \|x_k\|\ge m_k-1.$ Thus there is an infinite constant subsequence $m_{k_l}=:m.$ Hence
$$x_{k_l}=e_m+me_{n_{k_l}}\ {\rm and}\ \langle x_{k_l},e_m\rangle \ge 1$$
Therefore
$$\langle x,e_m\rangle =\lim_{l\to\infty}\langle x_{k_l},e_m\rangle \ge 1$$ which implies $x\neq 0.$

For every fixed $m$ the sequence $\{e_m+me_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ tends weakly to $e_m.$ Hence $e_m$ belongs to the sequential weak closure of $F.$ In turn the sequence $\{e_m\}_{m=1}^\infty $ tends weakly to $0.$ This shows $2.$